# What loader I need for JSX compile?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Hi I am new doing webpackconfig for compile my react js component and I am triying to compile it for publish in npm(I am unsing react I started using jsc classes etc but always the same error, so I translate to js, but again the same error :/ I'm lost) :

my babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "react-chat-bot42",
  "version": "0.6.7",
  "private": false,
  "description": "An ES6 npm module Chat Bot!",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Iñigo Romero",
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "Chabot",
    "react"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.13",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/InigoRomero/npm-Chat-Bot"
  }
}
```

my webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  }
}
```

The Error when I try to "**webpack --mode=development**" for compile:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 96:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (96:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|               return (
>       <div id="container" className="container">
|         <div id="chat" className="chat">
|           <div id="messages" className="messages"></div>
```

My source code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Dprompts, DReplies, DnotFound} from './DefaultConstants'
//import './DefaultStyle.css'
const reactChatBot = props => {
  let
    prompts = props.Prompts ? props.Prompts : Dprompts, 
    Replies = props.Replies ? props.Replies : DReplies,
    notFound = props.notFound ? props.notFound : DnotFound,
    botIcon = props.botIcon,
    userIcon = props.userIcon,
    input = '',
    text = '',
    product = '';
  window.onload = function() {
    let inputField = document.getElementById("input");
    inputField.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.code === "Enter") {
        input = inputField.value;
        inputField.value = "";
        output();
      }
    });
  }
    
  function output() {
    let product2;
    let text2 = input.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "").replace(/[\d]/gi, "").trim();
    text2 = text2
      .replace(/ a /g, " ") 
      .replace(/i feel /g, "")
      .replace(/whats/g, "what is")
      .replace(/please /g, "")
      .replace(/ please/g, "")
      .replace(/r u/g, "are you");
    text = text2;
    if (compare()) { 
      product2 = compare();
    } else if (text2.match(/thank/gi)) {
      product2 = "You're welcome!"
    } else {
      product2 = notFound[Math.floor(Math.random() * notFound.length)];
    }
    product = product2;
    addChat();
  }

  function compare() {
    let reply;
    let replyFound = false;
    for (let x = 0; x < prompts.length; x++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < prompts[x].length; y++) {
        if (prompts[x][y] === text) {
          let replies = Replies[x];
          reply = replies[Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length)];
          replyFound = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (replyFound) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return reply;
  }

  function addChat() {
    const messagesContainer = document.getElementById("messages");
    let userDiv = document.createElement("div");
    userDiv.id = "user";
    userDiv.className = "user response";
    userDiv.innerHTML = `<img src="`+ userIcon +`" class="avatar"><span>${text}</span>`;
    messagesContainer.appendChild(userDiv);

    let botDiv = document.createElement("div");
    let botImg = document.createElement("img");
    let botText = document.createElement("span");
    botDiv.id = "bot";
    botImg.src = botIcon;
    botImg.className = "avatar";
    botDiv.className = "bot response";
    botText.innerText = "...";
    botDiv.appendChild(botText);
    botDiv.appendChild(botImg);
    messagesContainer.appendChild(botDiv);
    messagesContainer.scrollTop = messagesContainer.scrollHeight - messagesContainer.clientHeight;


    setTimeout(() => {
      botText.innerText = `${product}`;
    }, 2000
    )

  }
        
        return (
      <div id="container" className="container">
        <div id="chat" className="chat">
          <div id="messages" className="messages"></div>
          <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Say something..." autoComplete="off" autoFocus={true} />
        </div>
      </div>
        );
};

export default reactChatBot;
```

and IF I try the webpack with this loader:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I got this error:

```
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In C:\Users\SapoArmado\Desktop\npm-Chat-Bot\node_modules\babel-preset-es2015\lib\index.js
Thanks for your time!
```

Comment: You need to configure babel-loader in your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: I try it but always get syntax error , so I am doing wrong but dont know why

Comment: What does your `webpack.config.js` look like with the proper loaders configured?

Comment: I have edited the question to add it

Comment: Look at the example here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/ Use should either be an array or you should use a higher level `loader: ` variable, not set `use` to a object.

Comment: You are using an absolute mishmash of Babel 6.x and Babel 7.x, which is why you are getting `Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects`. Keep `"babel-loader": "^8.2.2",` and convert everything else to `@babel/` with version 7.x

Answer (score 0):

Does your source file have a `.js` or `.jsx` extension? If it contains JSX syntax it should be `.jsx` or else compiler will complain

Comment: I am not sure , I can publish now

Comment: Not necessarily, only if you have configured webpack to use the JSX transpier for *only* for `.jsx` files.

Comment: done in the right way, editing the original question!